# Jenkins pipeline if condition not working

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses an if statement to check if a docker container is running. I run the following command to get the running state:

`def containerStatus = sh(script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l <user> <server> 'docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' ${tagName}'", returnStdout: true)`

I have added

`echo containerStatus`

and in the Jenkins console the output for this is "running"

However, when I have the following in the pipeline:

```
if(containerStatus.toString() == 'running'){
    echo 'Initial status: Container running'
    ...some code...
}
```

this condition is not executed (I hit my defined error condition). I have also tried removing the .toString(), but no luck.

The complete stage in the pipeline is:

```
stage("Container") {
    steps {
        script{
            def containerStatus = sh(script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l <user> <server> 'docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' ${tagName}'", returnStdout: true)
            echo containerStatus
            
            if(containerStatus.toString() == 'running'){
                echo 'Initial status: Container running'
                ...some code...
            }
            else {
                error "Container not running"
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trim the resulted output:

```
def containerStatus = sh(script: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l <user> <server> 'docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' ${tagName}'", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Comment: What is the reason trim() is required? Are there spaces returned with the string that needs to be removed?

Comment: I think it returns a newline